# Arabic letters aren't showing correctly in the plot

Tags: python, pandas, arabic, letter

I used all the correct encoding and the software does work but the letters in Arabic aren't connected (most Arabic letters are connected when written next to each other)

This is how the plot shows the image

[image]

I used the python Pandas module using the bar chart function

Comment: Please avoid links to a foreign site. Instead try giving the actual image here.

Comment: @InfectedDrake Sorry if it bothered you, I can't actually, stackoverflow does not allow uploading images unless I'm at a certain reputation score. The site I linked to is actually stackoverflow itself

Comment: Check out the `arabic_reshaper` python package: https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Awesome package, it seems to be working in most situations but trying to plot the series with Pandas it seems to mess it up to be just gibberish. I'll continue searching

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get around this is to take all the Arabic words in the pandas column that I need to plot and reshape it with `arabic_reshaper`, append them to a list and have this list as my x axis:

```py
# reshaping the arabic words to show correctly on matplotlib

import arabic_reshaper
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

x = [ ]

for item in df.column_name.values:
    x.append(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(item)))
```

Of course you need to install the `arabic_reshaper` and the `bidi.algorithm` packages first